# Form next to P tag

Tags: css

I want to archieve the following:
  I have a text wrapped in a p-tag and a submit-button together with a hidden input-field wrapped in a form-tag.
I want the text in the `<p>` tag and the button to **appear in the same line**, how can I do this (with css)?

```
<p>This is a example message text.</p><form method="POST"></input><input type="hidden" name="delete_message_id" value=" 1 "></input><input type="submit" value="delete"></input></form>
```

Since I want the hidden input field to be sent along with the submit event, I can not just leave away the wrapping form-tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `<p>` and `<form>` elements are displayed as block elements by default.

Change the 'display' CSS property to have them display inline:

```
p, form{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Also, `<input>` tags are self-closing; you don't include `</input>`. (Even you did, you have a further invalid `</input>` tag right after opening your `<form>`).

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e8qyffcj/1/)

Comment: and there is an extra </input>, right after <form>

Answer (score -1):

try adding this css style

```
<style>
p {
    display: inline;
}
</style>
```

or just set the element style

```
<p style="display: inline;">This is a example message text.</p><form method="POST"></input><input type="hidden" name="delete_message_id" value=" 1 "></input><input type="submit" value="delete"></input></form>
```